# Javascript API client vs Axios client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, axios

I am developing React Native app with redux-axios-middleware. I've been accessing APIs with axios clients like this:

```
const clients = {
  default: {
    client: axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://sandbox.iexapis.com",
      responseType: "json",
      params: {
        token: "",
      },
    }),
  },
  newsClient: {
    client: axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://newsapi.org/v2",
      responseType: "json",
      params: {
        apiKey: "",
      },
    }),
  },
  finnhub: {
    client: axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://finnhub.io/api/v1",
      responseType: "json",
      params: {
        token: "",
      },
    }),
  },
};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  applyMiddleware(multiClientMiddleware(clients))
);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default { store, persistor };
```

However, Finnhub api provides its own Client and the suggested use is like this: (from docs)

```
const finnhub = require('finnhub');
 
const api_key = finnhub.ApiClient.instance.authentications['api_key'];
api_key.apiKey = "<API_KEY>" // Replace this
const finnhubClient = new finnhub.DefaultApi()
 
// Stock candles
finnhubClient.stockCandles("AAPL", "D", 1590988249, 1591852249, {}, (error, data, response) => {
    console.log(data)
});
```

So, question is how can I make use of its client with redux-axios-middleware? If I am able to do that, then what is the difference between using API's client and the way I did(inside axios clients)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided package usually helps users get started with an API. This is specifically helpful if an API has authentication tokens that need to be refreshed. If you can read the documentation and work out the required API calls, you can continue using the Axios instance and not use the provided package. The package just adds some additional abstraction but if you look at the source code, it will end up making the same api calls that you could be making directly.